# Shipping Handling Charge CGI/Perl

Tags: perl, cgi

I want to add a flat $25 handling fee for Alaska (AK) and Hawaii (HI) - my test breaks when I add the states and flat fee to the shipping matrix below.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
my $totalPounds = sprintf("%.2f",($totalWeight / 16));
#my $shipping = &getShipUPS($totalPounds, $zip, $shipType);
if ($subtotal <= 24.99) {$shipping = '10.95';}
elsif (($subtotal > 24.99) && ($subtotal <= 74.99)) {$shipping = '13.95';}
elsif (($subtotal > 74.99) && ($subtotal <= 149.99)) {$shipping = '14.95';}
elsif ($subtotal >= $150) {$shipping = '18.95';}
elsif ($state eq 'HI','AK') ($subtotal <= 24.99) {$shipping = '10.95'+'25.00';}
elsif ($state eq 'HI','AK') (($subtotal > 24.99) && ($subtotal <= 74.99)) {$shipping = '13.95'+'25.00';}
elsif ($state eq 'HI','AK') (($subtotal > 74.99) && ($subtotal <= 149.99)) {$shipping = '14.95'+'25.00';}
elsif ($state eq 'HI','AK') ($subtotal >= $150) {$shipping = '18.95'+'25.00';}else 

$shipping = sprintf("%.2f", $shipping);

my $total = $subtotal + $tax + $shipping;
$subtotal = sprintf("%.2f", $subtotal);
$total = sprintf("%.2f", $total);
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use multiple parameters with `eq` like this

```
$state eq 'HI','AK'
```

You need to do

```
$state eq 'HI' or $state eq 'AK'
```

ALso, you cannot put another parenthesis after the first after `elsif` like this

```
elsif ($state eq 'HI','AK') ($subtotal >= $150)
```

You need to do

```
elsif ( ($state eq 'HI' or $state eq 'AK') or ($subtotal >= $150) )
#     ^----               main parantheses                 -------^
```

Of course, the smarter choice might be to use a hash

```
%extra_charges = ( AK => 25, 
                   HI => 25,
                   # etc
);
...
$subtotal += $extra_charges{$state};   # assuming no missing states
```

The if-else logic is also all kinds of redundant. This ought to be the equivalent of your code:

```
if    ($subtotal <= 24.99)            { $shipping = '10.95' }
elsif ($subtotal <= 74.99)            { $shipping = '13.95' }
elsif ($subtotal <= 149.99)           { $shipping = '14.95' }
else                                  { $shipping = '18.95' }

if ($state eq 'AK' or $state eq 'HI') { $shipping += 25 }
```

Those meandering forests of ifs are enough to make one dizzy, and most of them were not required. If a value is not less than or equal to 24.99, it must be bigger than 24.99, so no need to double check that.

Comment: Thanks TLP I agree the hash would make the smarter choice.  Testing now.

Comment: Don't forget to use `use strict; use warnings;`.

Answer (score 1):

That code is a total mess, has multiple syntax errors, and violates DRY.

It would be best to first calculate the basic shipping fee, depending on the subtotal. In a second step you add the $25 charge if the state is Hawaii or Alaska:

```
my @shipping_fees = (
  # max subtotal => fee
  [  24.99 => 10.95 ],
  [  74.99 => 13.95 ],
  [ 149.99 => 14.95 ],
  [ inf    => 18.95 ],
);

my %extra_fees_per_state = (
  AK => 25.00,
  HI => 25.00,
);
```

Then:

```
my $shipping;
for my $shipping_fee (@shipping_fees) {
  my ($max, $fee) = @$shipping_fee;
  if ($subtotal <= $max) {
    $shipping = $fee;
    last;
  }
}

if (defined( my $extra = $extra_fees_per_state{$state})) {
  $shipping += $extra;
}
```